# Working with random json nodes

Tags: c#, json

I wrote an application which is used to import new data from people into a database. The data I get is located on the web, that's working fine.

I used to work with the following structure:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "firstname": "John",
      "lastname": "Doe",
      "id": "1",
      "rfid": "BCDA412EA"
    },
    {
      "firstname": "Jane",
      "lastname": "Doe",
      "id": "2",
      "rfid": "DA412EBCA"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, I got a new "structure" that I can not handle. The new nodes are random generated values? How can I access those?

New json looks like this:

```
{
    "page": 0,
    "page_size": 200,
    "total_count": 5,
    "count": 5,
    "data": {
        "ab90708-ded183ab37b55-623f-42ae-ae51": {
            "firstname": "John",
            "lastname": "Doe",
            "created_at": "2015-09-16T15:51:39Z",
            "tags": [
                "803504",
                "80363004",
                "8436E64",
                "test123"
            ]
        },
        "34ba-0619-4ed8-bf168d2a-ce3af684a2b0": {
            "firstname": "Stefan",
            "lastname": "Baloh",
            "created_at": "2015-09-16T15:51:40Z",
            "tags": [
                "8034E26A4B0034004",
                "F3626A4B0034035"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Is it even possible to work with such a structure?

Comment: You need to show us your current code, tell us what you've tried. There are many different ways to do this.

Comment: How I have and how I try to work with the json: http://pastebin.com/f2KsZ6cJ - I have no clue what I should try to handle random names like this. I tried <dynamic> json as well as javascript component

Comment: What serializer/web API are you using?  See [Json serializers in ASP.NET and other](http://techblog.dorogin.com/2012/05/json-serializers-in-aspnet-and-other.html) for possibilities.  Basically this is easy to handle with Json.NET and `JavaScriptSerializer`, more difficult with WCF + `DataContractJsonSerializer`.

Comment: That's a very poorly structured json object. Those "random" values should be part of an array

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your classes as

```
public class User
{
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public List<string> tags { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int page { get; set; }
    public int page_size { get; set; }
    public int total_count { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, User>  data { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialize as (using [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json))

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
foreach(var user in obj.data.Values)
{
    Console.WriteLine(user.lastname);
}
```

The keyword here is the use of `Dictionary<string,...>` for these random names..

Comment: Please consider adding some namespace info for `JsonConvert`. It's not in the core .Net, even if it's well known Newtonsoft I suppose.